# Hi-jack form submit, store original submit, add processing, then submit normally

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a piece of javascript that I would like to add globally to my site.  This javascript using jQuery, would select any detected forms, store the original submit process, do some custom processing, then submit the form normally through the original process.

I have it working-ish with the code below, except when it "submits the form normally" I get a 'this.trigger is not a function' error for jQuery, but then the page posts/gets/etc to the appropriate destination.  I'd really like to try and remove the error if possible.  Any thoughts?

```
var originalForm = []
var originalSubmit = []
$('form').each(function(i) {
    originalForm[i] = this;
    originalSubmit[i] = $(this).submit;

    $(this).submit(function(e){
        // stop form
        e.preventDefault();

        // do processing
        // here

        // process form as it was originally intended
        $(this).unbind('submit');
        originalSubmit[i].apply(originalForm[i]);  
    });
});
```

HERE IS THE ERROR:

> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function
>       at HTMLFormElement.r.fn.(:8000/test/anonymous function) (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:6532)
>       at HTMLFormElement. (journey.js:915)
>       at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).submit` returns a reference to jQuery `submit` method, not to *"the original submit process"*. So it would be useless to store it.

The following would be enough:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  // stop form
  e.preventDefault();

  // do processing
  // here

  // process form as it was originally intended
  console.log(this.id, e.target.id)
  //this.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1"><input type="submit" value="submit 1"></form>

<form id="form2"><input type="submit" value="submit 2"></form>
```

Comment: Thank you Kosh, I like the simplicity of this solution, however, when I tried this I get "this.submit" is not a function.  I prefer this approach.  @taplar 's suggestion worked as expected, but I prefer this if I can get it to work.

Comment: would the method change if its in a loop?  $('form').each(function(i) { $(this).submit(function(e) { } ); });  Do I need the loop, since the selector will apply to everything it matches?

Comment: @sol, you do not have to loop. `$('form').submit(function)` sets handler to all the forms on the page. Just in case: you cannot submit several forms on the page simultaneously.

Comment: thank you. I've updated the code, still getting this.submit() is not a function...  I'm selecting the form with $('form[data-custom-attribute=value]').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();  this.submit();  } );

Comment: @sol, probably `this` changes somewhere, but you can replace it with `e.target.submit()`

Comment: :sad-face:  -- I removed all code but this.submit() or e.target.submit(); still no worky.  I now get e.target.submit() is not a function.

Comment: @sol, I've updated my answer with a code snippet to show you how it works. It would be great if you added a snippet to your question to show what's going on.

Comment: ok.  Thank you!  I now have it working without error, as well as discovered why it wasn't working. However, it fails in one circumstance.   If the input type=submit has a NAME of submit as well, it errors, because the reference is hitting that input not the form submission.  Is there a way to directly reference the submit action, like form.prototype.submit or something... in the event the form has a button with name = submit?

Comment: it appears if I change this.submit() to: HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(this);   can you share if "call' is the right method, or should "apply" be used.  Thanks!

Comment: @sol, it's not very good idea to have a form field with `name="submit"` as it would override `submit()` method. I'd suggest `name="is_submitted"` or so. Regarding `call` and `apply` there is no big difference which to use in this case.

Comment: totally agree, unfortunately this functionality is for a small plugin we provide for customers, whose pages I do not have control over...  Thank you for all of your help and responsiveness, we got this working using your example.

Comment: @sol, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
originalSubmit[i].apply(originalForm[i]);
```

Original form is a raw DOM Element, and you are trying to use it as the context for calling the jQuery submit method.  Given that that's not valid, you could do either...

```
originalSubmit[i].apply($(originalForm[i]));
```

...to make it a jQuery object, or possibly...

```
originalForm[i] = $(this);
```

...so it will already be a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Can use native submit which will not be listened to by jQuery submit listener and doesn't require removing it either

For example:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   var form = this;

   // when conditions met such as after some ajax perhaps    
   form.submit();

});
```